# How to add multiple entry to multiple model which have one to one relationship in django?

Tags: python, html, django, web-applications, django-apps

So I have these two models

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Questions/images", default="")
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    exam_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_asked = models.DateField(default="")


class Option(models.Model):
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text.null = True
    text.blank = True
    option_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Options/images", default="")
    option_image.null =True
    option_image.blank =True
    is_correct = models.BooleanField()
```

You see the question has one two many relationships with the options
Now I want to add question and corresponding to that question multiple options in the option table. So if a question with id=1 will have multiple option in option table with question_id = 1.

So I have made these two forms

```
from django import forms
from practice.models import Question
from practice.models import Option
from django.forms import ModelForm

class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['question_image', 'subject', 'topic', 'type' , 'exam_type' , 'date_asked']


class OptionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Option
        fields = ['text' , 'option_image' , 'is_correct']
```

Now in the HTML template in frontend I want to be able to add as many options I want so I have written this HTML code. The javascript code required to add more options is yet to be done but you get the point I am going to have multiple option forms and one question form. Look at HTML below for now lets just have **two option forms.**

```html
{% extends "users/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container">


  <div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Add Question</legend>
        {{ q_form|crispy }}
        <h4 class="border-bottom mb-4 pdb-2" style="padding-bottom : 1rem;">Options
          <button type="button" class="add-btn btn btn-success">+ Add Options</button>
        </h4>
        <div class="container text-left" id="option-list">


          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
              {{ o_form.text| as_crispy_field  }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
              {{ o_form.option_image| as_crispy_field  }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
              {{ o_form.is_correct| as_crispy_field  }}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
              {{ o_form.text| as_crispy_field  }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
              {{ o_form.option_image| as_crispy_field  }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
              {{ o_form.is_correct| as_crispy_field  }}
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>

      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Add Question</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from .forms import QuestionForm , OptionForm


def add(request):
    q_form = QuestionForm()
    o_form = OptionForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = QuestionForm(request.POST, request.FILE)
        o_form = OptionForm(request.POST,
                            request.FILE,
                            instance=request.question)
        if u_form.is_valid() and o_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            print("everthing saved")
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            print("not saved")
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        q_form = QuestionForm()
        o_form = OptionForm()


    context = {
    'q_form' : q_form,
    'o_form' : o_form
    }

    return render(request,'add_question/add.html' , context)
```

SO my question is how do I add multiple options to the same question id. And how do I pass the question id or the question instance to the options form so that it knows which question I am referring to add option. I want to add multiple options for one question how can I do this.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: This can be achieved using Formsets (specially inline_formset_factory). [This](https://micropyramid.com/blog/how-to-use-nested-formsets-in-django/) might solve your problem.

Comment: it is helpfull but while making the form I can set extra=2 or extra=3 according to my need but I want to have that extra a variable number and depends on how much option user want to add on the frontend. The extra can only be hard coded I want a interactive page where I can add as many option form I want using javascript.

Comment: To add it dynamically you need to write some javascript. [This](https://medium.com/all-about-django/adding-forms-dynamically-to-a-django-formset-375f1090c2b0) might help you.